# Removing an unnecessary login module in Apache Karaf

Tags: jaas, apache-karaf, karaf

This question was originally posted on the karaf users mailing list, but I didn't get an answer:
http://karaf.922171.n3.nabble.com/Deleting-an-unnecessary-login-module-td4033321.html

I would like to remove a login module (PublicKeyLoginModule) from the default jaas karaf realm.

According to the docs:
http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/developers-guide/security-framework.html

“So if you want to override the default security configuration in Karaf (which is used by the ssh shell, web console and
JMX layer), you need to deploy a JAAS configuration with the name name="karaf" and rank="1".”

However, when I do this new modules are added rather than replacing the existing ones.

When the blueprint below is loaded via either the deploy dir or via inclusion in a bundle (created using Maven by including the blueprint from the following path)
src\main\resources\OSGI-INF\blueprint\context.xml

I get the following:

```
karaf@root()> jaas:realm-list
Index | Realm Name | Login Module Class Name
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     | karaf      | org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.properties.PropertiesLoginModule
2     | karaf      | org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.publickey.PublickeyLoginModule
3     | karaf      | org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.ldap.LDAPLoginModule
```

What I would like to see is either

```
karaf@root()> jaas:realm-list
Index | Realm Name | Login Module Class Name
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     | karaf      | org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.ldap.LDAPLoginModule
```

Or, if there were a way to explicitly delete a module:

```
karaf@root()> jaas:realm-list
Index | Realm Name | Login Module Class Name
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     | karaf      | org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.properties.PropertiesLoginModule
2     | karaf      | org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.ldap.LDAPLoginModule
```

This is the blueprint:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:jaas="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/jaas/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0"
           xmlns:ext="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-ext/v1.0.0">

    <type-converters>
        <bean class="org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.properties.PropertiesConverter"/>
    </type-converters>

    <!-- Allow usage of System properties, especially the karaf.base property -->
    <ext:property-placeholder placeholder-prefix="$[" placeholder-suffix="]"/>

    <!-- AdminConfig property place holder for the org.apache.karaf.jaas  -->
    <cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="org.apache.karaf.jaas" update-strategy="none">
        <cm:default-properties>
            <cm:property name="example.group" value="example-group-value"/>
        </cm:default-properties>
    </cm:property-placeholder>

    <jaas:config name="karaf" rank="1">
        <jaas:module className="org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.ldap.LDAPLoginModule" flags="required">
            connection.url = ldap://ldap.example.com:389
            user.base.dn = o= example.com
            user.filter = (uid=%u)
            user.search.subtree = true
            role.base.dn = ou=applications,l=global,o= example.com
            role.filter = (&amp;(objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames)(uniqueMember=*uid=%u*)(cn=${ example.group}))
            role.name.attribute = cn
            role.search.subtree = true
            authentication = simple
        </jaas:module>
    </jaas:config>
</blueprint>
```

---

```
karaf@root()> shell:info
Karaf
  Karaf version               3.0.0
  Karaf home                  ***
  Karaf base                  ***
  OSGi Framework              org.apache.felix.framework - 4.2.1
```

Same issue on Karaf 3.0.1

I'd welcome any suggestions. Creating a whole new realm is a possibility, but for policy reasons I'd prefer not to have the PublicKeyLoginModule visible in the runtime at all.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can try this:

Default karaf realm is registered in `org.apache.karaf.jaas.module` bundle with blueprint.

Find the original `JaasRealm` service named `karaf` from the service registry and unregister it; then register your own realm using the above blueprint.